# VBA: Adding styles to hyperlinks in word

Tags: vba, hyperlink, ms-word

I'm trying to make a macro to add hyperlinks with different styles depending on level, each link on a new row in a table.

1. hyperlinktext1 (sub style1) (i.e bold and size 16)

   1.1 hyperlinktext2 (sub style2) (i.e size 14)

I have made sure that the styles exist and work for normal text but I can't get it to work with applying a style to a hyperlink added with VBA.

Changing styles works on hyperlinks I manually add for some reason.

```
    ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection.Range, Address:= _
    "file.pdf", SubAddress:="", ScreenTip:="", TextToDisplay:="text1"
    Selection.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Sub level1")

    'new row
    Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
    Selection.InsertRows 1
    Selection.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseStart

    ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection.Range, Address:= _
    "file2.pdf", SubAddress:="", ScreenTip:="", TextToDisplay:="text2"
    Selection.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Sub level2")
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

When you insert a hyperlink the selection range after the insertion is at the end of the hyperlink.  So in your code, when you apply your style, you are applying it to an insertion point at the end of your hyperlink.

To get the range of the hyperlink, so that you can apply a style to it, you can either move the start of the selection range, or better, capture the hyperlink when it is inserted.

In the first case you would add the line

```
Selection.MoveStart unit:=wdWord, count:=-1
```

after the add statement and before  the line that applies the style.

A better way to carry out your task is as below

```
Option explicit

Sub test()

    InsertHyperlinkWithStyle Selection.Range, "c:\path_to\file", ActiveDocument.Styles("Sub level1")

End Sub

Sub InsertHyperlinkWithStyle(this_range As Word.Range, this_file_path As String, this_style As Word.Style)

Dim my_hyperlink As Hyperlink

    Set my_hyperlink = ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks.Add( _
                        Anchor:=this_range.Duplicate, _
                        Address:=this_file_path, _
                        TextToDisplay:="text1")
    my_hyperlink.Range.Style = this_style

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your input Freeflow, but the links are still in size 16 no matter which style I try to add with your method

Comment: I suspect that this is a style issue.  When I checked on my system I found that the hyperlink changed correctly to show the applied style ONLY when the applied style was a character style.  If I applied a paragraph or linked style then the whole paragraph containing the link changed to match the style applied to the hyperlink.  So check that the styles you wish to apply to hyperlinks do have the correct font size, and that the styles are character styles.